# Fixing CSS classes with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a CTA in WordPress where the HTML looks like,

```
<p>
<a class="cta" href="...">CTA Button</a>
</p>
```

Further, I've styled the class `cta`. But now, the CSS is not looking great whenever the text wraps. Only now, I'm realizing that for a better looking CTA the CSS class should have been used in the `<p>` and not in the `<a>` tag.

Since I've followed this huge number of elements, changing them manually is nearly impossible. I'm sure this can also be achieved using JS, but I'm using AMP which makes such implementation really difficult.

Hence, I'd like to if this can be achieved using PHP or CSS?

Comment: Is all of this stored in a WYSIWYG, done through a shortcode, or some other way?

Comment: Loop through all `<a>` tags and if you find one with a `cta` class, remove that class and add it to its parent: `document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(a => { if(a.classList.contains("cta") { a.classList.remove("cta"); e.parentElement.classList.add("cta"); } });`

Comment: The “can this be achieved using CSS” part of the question should be answered by [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1427878)

Comment: @ChrisHaas It is stored in the WordPress classic editor. No shortcode involved.

Comment: @WaisKamal can the same be done through PHP? As I'm using AMP, running this JS seems difficult.

Comment: @CBroe It seems like browsers don't support `:has()` pseudo class to implement this with CSS.

Comment: Why not add a class to the parent `p` and then use css to select down to the `a.cat`?

Comment: @NirmalKumar you can use the answer below, or alternatively `echo` a `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP solution:

```
<?php
// example code

$html=<<<EOT
<p>
<a class="cta" href="...">CTA Button</a>
</p>
<p>
<a class="dontreplaceme" href="...">CTA Button</a>
</p>
<p><a class="cta" href="...">
CTA Button</a>
</p><p><a class="cta" href="...">CTA Button</a></p>
<p><a class="cta" href="...">CTA Button</a></p>
EOT;
$delim = 'class="cta"';
// remove white spaces between tags
$html = explode($delim, preg_replace('/\>\s+\</m', '><', $html));
$new = [];
foreach($html as $seg) {
    // check end of segment for a match
    if(strcmp(substr($seg, -6), '<p><a')>0) {
        $seg = substr($seg,0,-6).'<p ' . $delim . '><a';
    }
    $new[]= $seg;
}
$new = implode("",$new);
print_r($new);
```

Example: https://www.tehplayground.com/XPVv3i8kRxXI0mJ7

---

Javascript solution (archived) since you want a PHP one

This will run after the page has rendered and will remove 'cta' from the 'a' tags and place it in the closest 'p' parent

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => { 
   document.querySelectorAll('a.cta')
   .forEach(e=>{ 
      e.classList.remove('cta');
      e.closest('p').classList.add('cta');
   }); 
})
```

Which compresses down to a tidy one-liner

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => { document.querySelectorAll('a.cta').forEach(e=>{e.classList.remove('cta');e.closest('p').classList.add('cta');}); })
```

Comment: I won't be able to run this code inside an AMP framework as they have their own restrictions in running JS.

Comment: @NirmalKumar - updated with a PHP solution - and just edited to be more precise